# 1-1 Mapping (with no unique key identifier) of JSON object in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have a list of JSON objects, converted from the result of a SQL query. The JSON looks like this:

```
[ {
        "CREATE_DATE_TIME" : "2018-02-04 11:00:03.0",
        "EXTERNAL_ID" : "1111",
        "CERT_NUMBER" : "123",
        "DESCRIPTION" : "DESC 1",
        "SOURCE_SYSTEM" : "WOULDIWAS"
    }, {
        "CREATE_DATE_TIME" : "2018-03-01 11:25:03.0",
        "EXTERNAL_ID" : "2222",
        "CERT_NUMBER" : "456",
        "DESCRIPTION" : "DESC 2",
        "SOURCE_SYSTEM" : "SHOOKSPEARE"
    }, 
    ... 
]
```

The output after JSON transform should be something like this:

```
{
    "Jobs": [
        {
            "Notification": {
                "ActivityDate" : "2018-02-04 11:00:03.0",
                "ExternalId" : "1111",
                "CertNum" : "123",
                "Description" : "DESC 1",
                "SourceSystem" : "WOULDIWAS",
                "RecordType" : "Task Notification"
            }, {
            "Notification": {   
                "ActivityDate" : "2018-03-01 11:25:03.0",
                "ExternalId" : "2222",
                "CertNum" : "456",
                "Description" : "DESC 2",
                "SourceSystem" : "SHOOKSPEARE",
                "RecordType" : "Task Notification"
            }, 
        ... 
    ]
}
```

(The RecordType is a literal string, not derived from the input JSON)

Each row / entry (JSON object enclosed in {}) in the input JSON is guaranteed to be unique but there is no key here that would indicate that. The row / entry in the input should correspond 1-1 to `{ Notification: {...} }` in the output. How should I construct my Jolt Spec to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to sound offending or anything, but you should've posted what you've already tried.
Anyway here's the spec to get your intended output format

`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Jobs[].Notification"
    }
  }
]`

I would suggest you try out renaming the fields yourself, because practicing JOLT is the best way to learn

If you still need help, I'll complete the answer for you.

Here's a few reading material [Documentation](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#Documentation), the [Slide deck](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1sAiuiFC4Lzz4-064sg1p8EQt2ev0o442MfEbvrpD1ls/edit?usp=sharing).
And you can learn a lot from the [issues page](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues) where Milo Simpson has already solved queries for most of your questions.